# jQuery/AJAX Syntax - PHP vs ASP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a tutorial that explains how to use jQuery to Get and Post data from an external page. The tutorials are generally simple, but this one is confusing because the external data is stored in pages with an .asp extension, which I know nothing about.

How should I modify the text from these pages so it works with PHP?

```
<%
response.write("This is some text from an external ASP file.")
%>

<%
dim fname,city
fname=Request.Form("name")
city=Request.Form("city")
Response.Write("Dear " & fname & ". ")
Response.Write("Hou live well in " & city & ".")
%>
```

Comment: I've never used ASP either, but by just looking at the code it looks like `response.write` is how you `echo`.  It also looks like `Request.Form("name")` is `$_REQUEST['name']` (you'd normally use `$_GET` or `$_POST` depending on which you want).

Comment: I guess you should look for a better tutorial, that uses the languages you want.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would be easier in the long run. This is a W3Schools tutorial. I thought that was one of the best; I didn't realize they were Microsofties. ;)

Comment: I wouldn't actually suggest using W3Schools' tutorials.  You can probably find better ones elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In FE Script jQuery like this. "test.php"

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"data":"check"},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data.value1);
        alert(data.value2);
    }
 });
```

### PHP Script

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data'] == 'check'){
       //Data 1
         $data['value1'] = 'Data 1 Got Successfully';
        //Data 2
         $data['value2'] = 'Data 2 Got Successfully';
         $resonse = json_encode($data);
         echo $response;
    }
?>
```

I hope you're aware of how to inject the response to DOM in AJAX success function

Comment: "inject the response to DOM in AJAX success function" ??? I don't even know what that means; I'm just learning the ropes. I'm looking for a better tutorial right now. ;)

Comment: like in my code the success function has receiving object data. And  by that data you could inject the result/response to any html areas. For example if you want to update a textbox value from the ajax result you can use $('#textBoxID').val(data.value1);. Please check jQuery Tutorials for more updates.

Comment: Thx; that's a good tip. My ultimate goal is to make a series of online quizzes combining PHP, jQuery and AJAX. It's really frustrating when half the projects I download from online tutorials don't even work. But I should be able to pull it together piece by piece.